# Sql Query for range

Tags: sql, sql-server, range

i am developing a website 
there are two form searchscreen and serachresultscreen 
in first form i select a range from two dropdown list (i.e From value1 to value 2)

range is for diamond clarity like in order respectively

```
FL,IF,VVS,VVS1,VVS2,SI,SI1,I1,I2
```

when i range query it on next form like

```
clarity>=FL and clarity<=VVS1
```

then it show result with all values between alphabet F to V (i.e `FL,IF,VVS,VVS1,VV2,SI,I1,I2`

please suggest me some answere

My required output is(when selected between from=FL to=VVS1)
then result output  value `FL,IF,VVS,VVS1` only

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @Bohemian : SQL SERVER

Comment: @rajsingh, see answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use range operator `BETWEEN` for your String values. To address this issue create table with corresponding numeric weighting for those Diamond Clarity values.

while filtering based on Clarity fetch its order and then put all those ORDER (Numeric Number)
within Range Operator

**EDIT :**

```
CREATE TABLE DIAMOND_CLARITY
(CLARITY VARCHAR(10),
 CLARITY_ORDER int
)

INSERT INTO DIAMOND_CLARITY values ('FL',1)
INSERT INTO DIAMOND_CLARITY values ('IF',2)
INSERT INTO DIAMOND_CLARITY values ('VVS',3)
INSERT INTO DIAMOND_CLARITY values ('VVS1',4)
INSERT INTO DIAMOND_CLARITY values ('VVS2',5)
INSERT INTO DIAMOND_CLARITY values ('SI',6)
INSERT INTO DIAMOND_CLARITY values ('SI1',7)
INSERT INTO DIAMOND_CLARITY values ('I1',8)
INSERT INTO DIAMOND_CLARITY values ('I2',9)
```

**Query to fetch records between ranges**

```
    SELECT CLARITY from DIAMOND_CLARITY where CLARITY_ORDER 
BETWEEN
    (SELECT CLARITY_ORDER FROM DIAMOND_CLARITY where CLARITY='FL')
    AND 
    (SELECT CLARITY_ORDER FROM DIAMOND_CLARITY where CLARITY='VVS')
```

Comment: :Thank u for helping me. U answer was helpful for solving my problem :))))))

Comment: My guess is because it's a solution, but an inelegant one. I'll look into this a bit later